# Ignore a specific file when committing .idea/dictionaries/ancar.xml

Tags: git, commit

In my project I have the following xml ".idea/dictionaries/ancar.xml" as an .idea file.

What can I do in order to have this document avoided in my git commit?

.gitignore does not seem to work (even though I have this added *.idea in my .gitignore file) - and I already have some .idea files in my GIT repository (maybe this is why now avoids them?)

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify the issue please - have you tried adding the document path to the .gitignore? What happened? Gitignore provides exactly the function you are looking for.

Comment: Well in my project in GIT repository we already have some .idea files and I suppose .gitignore does not avoid this kind of files anymore (but we still have *.idea added in .gitignore file - and however this did not work).

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach, seems to work for the moment. However I will appreciate any other ideas. Thanks!

```
git rm -rf .idea
git commit -m "delete .idea"
git push
```